# How to render nested folders in a Data View Web Part?

Tags: data-view-web-part

I want to use a Data Vew Web Part to render the nested folder structure of a document library. I can get as far as using grouping on the path and setting the datasource to recursive. That effectively renders the folders in a flat view rather than nested.

How can I get nesting?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need to create a recursive XSL template to make things look the way you want.  There isn't anything "out of the box".